# How can I access the security context token from the view layer in symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

If I had a user object stored in the session, I could retrieve the user name in twig using somthing like:

```
app.session.get('user').UserName
```

But my user object (`UserInterface`) resides in the security context, more specifically in the user field of the userToken (TokenInterface) object. How can I access values inside the user object from twig? I am thinking of something along the lines of:

```
app.security.context.token.user.[my_user_property]
```

Answer (score 23):

The security context is available from the `app` global as `security`:

```
{{ app.security.getToken().getUser() }}
```

will output the string representation of your user object (or "anon." if you're not logged in, but are authenticated).

Note that unless you have declared public properties, you'll have to use your getter/setter methods:

```
{{ app.security.getToken().getUser().getUsername() }}
```

As a shortcut you can use the `set` tag to define a user variable in the template:

```
{% set user = app.security.getToken().getUser() %}
```

and save yourself a lot of typing, or pass it in from the controller.

Comment: This is totally sick and stupid - one time the symfony security.context->getToken()->getUser() returns User Entity Object, the next time it returns a string = "anon.". This is agaisnt every single principle, a terrible contruction...

Comment: twig is pretty smart about using getters, so `app.security.token.user.username` should work

Comment: app.security method is deprecated since version 2.6. Use app.user instead.

Answer (score 20):

In our project, we use the `app object`. It's a `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables`

This object has a method `getUser` to access the user in the security context.

So in your code you can use

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

to retrieve the user in your views.

Comment: {{ app.user }} gives you the user entity indicated in your security context. Keep in mind that app.user is null for anonymously authenticated routes, so you'll like to check if the user exists in that page or not before accessing any of its properties.

Answer (score 14):

Just a note, Twig has a feature where you can check if a user has a given role from the view layer:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```